# Multiple MySQL Queries in ONE While Ignoring Duplicate Matched IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I asked a question [Combine Multiple MySQL Queries on the Same Table Into One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379228/combine-multiple-mysql-queries-on-the-same-table-into-one) and received a [noteworthy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29381060/804104) thanks to [`@Paul Griffin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632864/paul-griffin).

As stated in my other question linked above, I have multiple queries combined into one query. These queries consist of exact matching and broad matching search terms.

I am searching through posts on a WordPress website. Just to keep things simple, I'm looking through the following columns in the posts table: `post_title` (Article Title), `post_name` (Article URL Slug), and `post_excerpt` (Article Summary).

Just to keep things even simpler for the sake of this question, let's say I have a search term of "Floor Finish", and I'm only searching through the column `post_title`.

As stated earlier, I'm looking for exact matches and broad matches.

**So three searches will be placed:**

1. Floor Finish
2. Floor
3. Finish

**That would produce a query like:**

```
( SELECT `ID`, `post_title` FROM `tps_3_posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_title` LIKE '%floor finish%' ) 

UNION 

( SELECT `ID`, `post_title` FROM `tps_3_posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_title` LIKE '%floor%' ) 

UNION 

( SELECT `ID`, `post_title` FROM `tps_3_posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_title` LIKE '%finish%' )
```

After examining my query, I began to realize that's not very efficient.

It's placing the "Exact Match" ("Floor Finish") search first, followed by each of the "Broad Match" ("Floor", "Finish") searches.

So the first go around, finds all posts with "Floor Finish" somewhere in the title of the article.

So there should already a list of ID's selected.

Now, when MySQL goes to place the second search (The first "Broad Match" ("Floor") search.) It's looking through ALL posts to find an article title match containing "Floor". This includes looking through the same posts which have already been located from the exact match (Which I don't want -- Seems redundant.).

This same behavior is continued for each broad search. Thus causing unnecessary searching.

So is there any way, with multiple queries combined into one, that each following query DOESN'T look through posts which an `ID` (column), and `post_title` (column) has already been selected?

Or another way of wording it... Each query that's selecting the same columns, but has a different search term, checks to see if an `ID` (column) and `post_title` (column) has already been selected, and if so, ignore that `ID`, and continue looking for new `ID`'s which haven't already been selected.

Or does MySQL already handle that internally since I'm issuing multiple queries combined into one query?

**EDIT**

It seems I was over complicating it all. Using the selected answer, and querying all three columns as mentioned towards the top of my question. (`post_title`, `post_name`, `post_excerpt`)

The query looks like this:

```
(

SELECT `ID` , `post_name` , NULL AS `post_title` , NULL AS `post_excerpt`
FROM `tps_3_posts`
WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' 
AND (
`post_name` LIKE '%floor-finish%' OR 
`post_name` LIKE '%floor%' OR 
`post_name` LIKE '%finish%'
)

) UNION (

SELECT `ID` , NULL AS `post_name` , `post_title` , NULL AS `post_excerpt`
FROM `tps_3_posts`
WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' 
AND (
`post_title` LIKE '%floor finish%' OR 
`post_title` LIKE '%floor%' OR 
`post_title` LIKE '%finish%'
)

) UNION (

SELECT `ID` , NULL AS `post_name` , NULL AS `post_title` , `post_excerpt`
FROM `tps_3_posts`
WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' 
AND (
`post_excerpt` LIKE '%floor finish%' OR 
`post_excerpt` LIKE '%floor%' OR 
`post_excerpt` LIKE '%finish%'
)

)
```

Comment: You would have to do an `EXPLAIN` to see what indexes were being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `or`:

```
SELECT `ID`, `post_title`
FROM `tps_3_posts`
WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND
      (`post_title` LIKE '%floor finish%' OR
       `post_title` LIKE '%floor%' OR
       `post_title` LIKE '%finish%'
      );
```

MySQL is not going to parse the `LIKE` expression and determine that one like is a subset of another.

EDIT:

If you want to know how many of the values match, just include the information in the `select`:

```
SELECT `ID`, `post_title`,
       ((`post_title` LIKE '%floor finish%') +
        (`post_title` LIKE '%floor%') +
        (`post_title` LIKE '%finish%')
       ) as nummatches          
FROM `tps_3_posts`
WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND
      (`post_title` LIKE '%floor finish%' OR
       `post_title` LIKE '%floor%' OR
       `post_title` LIKE '%finish%'
      );
```

An exact match will have a value of 3.

Comment: I suppose I could just do it like that, and then use PHP to determine whether it's an exact match or broad match. I was just trying to accomplish as much as possible in one swift motion.